# How to find the version of AMQP protocol used in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp

Is there any way to check the version (1.0 or 0.9.1) of AMQP that is being used by ActiveMQ. I'm using ActiveMQ 5.16.3.

In the RabbitMQ console there is a way to view the version of AMQP protocol that is being connected. I want to check if there are any ways to verify the version of AMQP protocol that is being connected in the ActiveMQ web console.

Comment: Which version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.16.3 version of activemq.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated your question with the extra details you provided. All such relevant information should be in the question itself rather than scattered in various comments.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're starting a *new* project I recommend you use [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/). It is the next-generation broker from ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveMQ "Classic" (i.e. 5.x) **only** supports AMQP 1.0. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/amqp) for more details.

There is no way to see the protocol version in the web console and really no need since only AMQP 1.0 is supported.

Comment: In RabbitMQ console, there is a way to view the version of amqp protocol that is being connected. Posted this to verify if there are any ways to verify the version of amqp protocol that is being connected in activemq web console.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks It helped.